# How can I call class functions from a Form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class

```
Public Class gFunctions
    Public Function gSerialPortWrite(ByVal msg As String, comport As Object)
        SerialPort1.Write(msg)
    End Function

    'Pinvoke.Net stackoverflow.com/questions/11238898/reading-from-an-ini-file
    Public Declare Auto Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpAppName As String,
        ByVal lpKeyName As String,
        ByVal lpDefault As String,
        ByVal lpReturnedString As StringBuilder,
        ByVal nSize As Integer,
        ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
    Public Declare Auto Function WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
        (ByVal lpSectionName As String,
        ByVal lpKeyName As String,
        ByVal lpValue As String,
        ByVal lpFilename As String) As Integer
End Class
```

How do I call these functions in my `form1.vb` if I place them in my `class1.vb`? thanks for any help or added information. New to Visual Studio, although I have experience with VB in Excel. In Excel I just added another `module.bas`.

Comment: You... instantiate the class and call the functions? What was your attempt so far?

Comment: You can add the `Shared` keyword, so you can call `gFunctions.GetPrivateProfileString(...)` etc directly; but that's not the way to declare Win32 functions. See the [`<DllImport>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.-ctor) way. Also, how to specify a [CharSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset) Field value.

Comment: This won't work with the `gSerialPortWrite()` function as this is using `SerialPort1`, which presumably resides on a Form.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the serial port, but how do I what do add shared keyword to?My attempt so far, I tried calling the functions from my form like I did in Excel, then I tried gFunctions.GetPrivateProfileString but neither of those work.

Comment: You can use a module in VB.NET too. Replace  `Public Class gFunctions ... End Class` with `Module gFunctions ... End Module` and they will be accessible anywhere in your project. Also as mentioned, consider using the right signatures of the kernel functions, copy them from Pinvoke.Net. As for the `SerialPort1` which seems  a Form member as mentioned, you can make it a function argument like: `Public Function gSerialPortWrite(ByVal msg As String, comport As Object, SerPort As SerialPort) ... End Function`. Lastly, the `comport` shouldn't be an `Integer` ?

Comment: Although I wouldn’t recommend this myself, could always declare a form level instance of gFunctions, then your form will have access to all the properties and methods of the class